# PHP: how to sort an array by keys numerically?

Tags: php, sorting, ksort

Even though I have read the PHP documentation and this looks like to be a FAQ, it's still giving me some headache.

I have an array like this which holds the months of the year:

```
[12] => december
 [4] => april
 [3] => march
 [6] => june
 [7] => july
[10] => october

...and so on
```

The order is not as it should be. I want to reorder the keys numerically. I can swap the keys with values if I want, but while each numerical value will match the corresponding month, they will never be in order. So I thought of putting these in order via PHP.

I have tried with `$calendar = ksort( $myarray );`

But If I try to print `$calendar`, I will only get bool=true or array with a single key and "1" as value... I was planning to use the ksort result in a foreach later, but I can't.

What I'm droing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No .. just use:

```
ksort($myarray);
print_r($myarray)
```

[Codepad example](http://codepad.org/kQihb8K8)

[ksort()](http://uk.php.net/ksort) sorts an array by key, maintaining key to data correlations, returns `TRUE` on success or `FALSE` on failure, if you associate the `$calendar` with `ksort()` you will have what `ksort` returns.

Comment: thanks, I just got that - I didn't understand what the PHP manual was trying to say and assumed I had to store the sorted array into a variable

Answer (score 0):

```
ksort($arr);
foreach ($arr as $key => $val) 
{ 
   echo "$key = $val\n";
}
```